# How to scrape url using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Now i am scraping product information form e-commerce website like product name, prize, color, category and description using node.js. But now i want to know how scrape the url(http://www.amazon.in/Folding-Rechargeable-Light-Foldable-studying/dp/B00KP3IVBM/ref=sr_1_4?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1459151675&sr=1-4) from address bar. Somebody please help me.

Comment: have you checked nodejs modules Request and Cheerio ?

Comment: Using the official Amazon Product Advertisement API would be better than scraping their websites.

Comment: yes i fixed the problem. Like before i get the scrape values i sent the url to node.js. That same thing i had taken back to controller. Thank You.